# ios(swift) location in background (ios 9.3.2) stops working

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I am not sure if this is a bug or some sort of configuration issue but(but i put every option in info.plist, locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true and every other tip i found on the web and still the problem exists)

locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
}

stops updating the location after some (random) time when in background (the app closed).  On a iphone 4s ios 8.4 this problem is not present.

Maybe some one else confrunted this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your code ?

Comment: Did you solve your problem. I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Me too. It seems to happen with no reason, just stop tracking also if you registered some regions in the background. Does anybody figured it out? Is it really a bug? With 9.3.1 it never happen to me...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it restarting the location manager every 3 minutes:

In your delegate method (`locationDidUpdateToLocation` in my case) put something like

```
     self.timeElapsedSinceLastTrackingUpdate = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(self.lastUpdatedTime)
     if timeElapsedSinceLastTrackingUpdate > 180 {
        self.lastUpdatedTime = NSDate()         
        self.LocationMgr.stopUpdatingLocation()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler({})                
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(180, target: self.LocationMgr, selector: #selector(self.LocationMgr.startUpdatingLocation), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
     }
```

Also Make sure you have both keys (`NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`) in your `Info.plist`

```
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs to use your location</string>

    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs to use your location</string>
```

And finally, be sure to set these variables on the location manager:

`pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false`

and

```
allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
```

Comment: I tested it on iOS 10 and it didn't work for me. After some time (don't know exactly how long) it stops getting the location when in background.

Comment: same here, in my case it stopped after 15 minutes. I tested on iPhone6 Plus and iOS 10.0.1

Answer (score 0):

In addition you also can use the significant change location service, with this service, even when your is suspend, the iOS will wake your app

look for: startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges in:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem. the way I have found to solve this problem is go to `settings` -> `privacy` -> `location services` -> find your app -> `allow location access` -> switch to `never` -> go back to `location services` -> then `allow location access` to switch on your service again. but only work sometimes.

also, as I know(may be I'm worry.) if the accuracy is not enough that what you have set. location update wouldn't be fired up.